# Node does not break at first line when started as "node --debug-brk"

Tags: node.js, node-inspector

The following file is started as **node --debug-brk hello-http.js**

**hello-http.js**

```
// Load the http module to create an http server.
var http = require('http');

// Configure our HTTP server to respond with Hello World to all requests.
var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.end("Hello World\n");
});

// Listen on port 8000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
server.listen(8000);

// Put a friendly message on the terminal
console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/");
```

At the first line the program is expected to break and until the continue command is given using node-inspector(running on another terminal) the last line console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/"); is not supposed to be printed. But as soon as the node starts it does not break and prints the log.

```
$ node --debug-brk hello-http.js 
Debugger listening on port 5858
Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

Using **node version v0.12.0** running on a ubuntu-12.04 LTS machine
How to make it break on the first line(i.e var http = require('http');).

**UPDATE 1:**

After rebooting the machine

1. The **node --debug-brk hello-http.js** waits for the debugger to be connected as displayed

   $ node --debug-brk hello-http.js 
   Debugger listening on port 5858
2. **node-inspector** is stared on another terminal
3. As soon the chrome browser connects to **node-inspector** at  http://127.0.0.1:8080/debug?port=5858 the **node** programs continues execution(printing **Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000**) with out waiting for the debugger to send commands.

   $ node --debug-brk hello-http.js 
   Debugger listening on port 5858
   Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Is this expected. If yes, how to make node-inspector send breakpoint command to set the breakpoint at the first line.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Do you have a debugger running somewhere? Perhaps your debugger is making it move on right away?

Comment: After reboot the node program waits for the debugger to connect. However as soon as the node-inspector connects the programs starts exectuing without stopping at the first line. Please look the update in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just looks like a bug in `node-inspector`.

https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/534

Answer (score 2):

This is known issue of Node Inspector when running on a post-v0.10 version of Node (0.12, 1.x), see https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/534.